# OnClickListener inside custom alertdialog Android

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I am a self-taught beginner and appreciate patience! Thanks!

In Eclipse, I made a custom alertdialog with its own xml file ("custom_dialog") and it is called "usernamealert".

I want an alert to pop-up if the user hasn't entered a username yet (ie, username.length == 0).

Inside this layout I have a textView ("What is your name?"), editText and button ("usernameButton").

Before putting in the onclicklistener for the button, everything worked. This was my (relevant) Java:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup)     getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder usernamebuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
usernamebuilder.setView(dialoglayout);

AlertDialog usernamealert = usernamebuilder.create();
```

When I put the onclicklistener in, it broke! Where should I have put it?

(the following is what I had tried... all in my OnCreate)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup)getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder usernamebuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
usernamebuilder.setView(dialoglayout);


Button usernameButton = (Button) usernamealert.findViewById(R.id.usernameButton);
usernameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {  
//store username in sharedprefs
usernamealert.dismiss();



}
});
```

After the code I said:

```
if (username.length() == 0) {
            usernamealert.show();
        }
```

Again, it worked before I started messing with the button!!

Comment: After hours of searching, and finally posting the question, I just figured it out like 2 minutes later! 

All I should have done differently was change how it found the button:

    Button usernameButton = (Button)usernamealert.findViewById(R.id.usernameButton);

it should have been:

    Button usernameButton = (Button)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.usernameButton);

// dialoglayout is whatever you called the View

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please post your solution as an answer and accept it as the correct answer after it allows you to. That will make it easier for people in the future to find the solution if they have the same problem.

Comment: your answer helped me.. though please make your answer more readable.. im going to add my answer below

Answer (score 11):

It is needed to specify where will the code search the button, if its only "findViewById" it would search in the xml of the host, it should be

```
LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
                View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoghireteachernegotiate, null);
                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                builder.setView(myview);
                 Button addS = (Button) myview.findViewById (R.id.bAddS);
```

This is part of my class, Hireteachernegotiate.class, which has a layout of hireteachernegotiate.xml

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
                View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoghireteachernegotiate, null);
                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                builder.setView(myview);

                Button addS = (Button) myview.findViewById (R.id.bAddS);
                addS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //do some stuff
                    }
                });

                Button minusS = (Button) myview.findViewById (R.id.bMinusS);
                addS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       //do other stuff
                    }
                });

                // Add action buttons
                       builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                               dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                   builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });   



            builder.show();
```

This is the dialog layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAddS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMinusS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
usernamebuilder.setCancelable(false)
usernamebuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //do what you want.
       }
   });
```

See if that works, or if it helps in some way.

Comment: How do i dismiss this dialog when I add a custom onClickListener on an ImageView?

Comment: @4ndro1d  Use "dialog.dismiss();" inside the onClick method that is within the setOnClickListener();