# Android Application crash on dialog Button click

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make a Dialog close when button is pressed.But Every time i press the button the application crashes.

```
public class CanvasPaint extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    final Button widthbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widthbtn);
    final  Button widthpopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widthpopBtn);

    final Context context = this;

    final Dialog widthDialog = new Dialog(context);

    widthbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                widthpopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        widthDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                widthDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please examine your LogCat and look at your stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @jyoon The second onclick is for the button within the dialog

Comment: If the second is within the dialog, you need to inflate the layout properly. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168358/onclicklistener-inside-custom-alertdialog-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's some inception code. Why are you setting a click listener inside a click listener? It should be more like

```
widthbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            widthDialog.show();
    }
});

widthpopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            widthDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: When i do it this way the application crash a pon loading

Comment: Then either widthbtn or widthpopBtn is null. As @CommonsWare already stated above, check your logcat/stack trace. Also the Dialog you're showing is dead empty if the code you posted is the actual code in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog layout is **not** properly inflated, and therefore, your `widthpopBtn` will be null. Try inflating the layout like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null);
Button widthpopBtn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.widthpopBtn);
```